# Stop Vercel preview deployments on Dependabot PRs

Tags: bash, git, github, deployment, vercel

I want to stop **Vercel** from creating **preview deployments** for the **dependabot pull requests**.

In Vercel, in the **Ignored Build Step** I've tried this:

```bash
bash vercel.sh
```

and in my repo, the vercel.sh file looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "VERCEL_ENV: $VERCEL_ENV"

# check branch name
BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
echo "BRANCH: $BRANCH"

# check if branch name does not contain "Bump" (every dependabot PR starts with this)
if [[ $BRANCH != *"Bump"* ]]; then
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

What am I missing? The deployment still went through.

Also tried writing this right to the **Ignored Build Step**

```bash
if [ "$VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_LOGIN" == "dependabot" ]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi
```

Still created the deployment.

#### Tried it this way too

```js
if (process.env.VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_LOGIN === "dependabot") {
  process.exit(0);
} else {
  process. Exit(1);
}
```

and then calling it like `node ignore-nuild.js` in the **Ignored Build Step**, but this didn't help either.

#### Update

My bad, it was "dependabot[bot]", not just "dependabot".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, always surround with quotes a variable you want to echo. That way, you can catch the invisible space which might plague its value:

```
echo "BRANCH: '${BRANCH}'"
             ^^^       ^^^
```

Second, you can add `echo` before the exit, to differentiate when you `exit 1` from `exit 0`.

```bash
echo "continue"
exit 0
```

Third, you can try, for testing:

```
if [[ "${BRANCH#Bump}" != "${BRANCH}" ]]; then ...
```

If `$BRANCH` starts with `Bump`, then the condition will be true.

---

The OP suggests:

```bash
if (process.env.VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_LOGIN === "dependabot[bot]") {
  process.exit(0);
} else {
  process. Exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Navigate to your project settings: https://vercel.com/user/slug/settings/git
2. Update the build ignore step to "custom" and enter:

```bash
[ "$VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_LOGIN" == "dependabot[bot]" ]
```

[image: image of the above steps]